# How does one make sure that their rails environment on one machine is the same as another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, operating-system, md5

I have three macs.  I have a rails app, that I can run on two of them.  On the third, I can create a new rails app and it works fine and some of my other rails apps from the other machines work fine, however the one that I need to have work on the one machine always gives me a message about not being able to find an image:

```
/Users/woo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': dlopen(/Users/woo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/woo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

I have followed suggestions about installing the mysql2 bundle using:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\"
```

then bundle install, and it says all is fine.  Yet 'rails s' produces that unable to find image message.

I use rbenv to manage versions and on all machines ruby is 2.6.3 and rails is 5.2.4.

What other aspects of the configuration of the app do I need to check to make sure they are the same?  I have a script called 'laptop' that I obtained using:

```
cd ~
curl --remote-name https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monfresh/laptop/master/mac
curl --remote-name https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monfresh/laptop/master/Brewfile
/usr/bin/env bash mac 2>&1 | tee ~/laptop.log
```

I run this on each machine when I am setting up to install or run a rails app.  On the problem machine I do get messages like:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
```

during the laptop run, but at the end it says all modules were installed correctly.  I have a feeling that's not really true and may be part of the problem.  If so, what is causing this?  I'm running OS X 10.14.6 on the machine in question.

I also notice that libssl.1.0.0.dylib is NOT present at the specified location.  How do I install this and moreover, how to I make sure that all of these pieces are properly coordinated?

Comment: This is more of an opinion, but recommend looking at Docker if your goal is to have a unified environment.  There is a book called Docker for Rails developers that should get you out of the gate.

Comment: Have used Docker, but I need this installed on my laptop.  Thanks.

Comment: Went through complete removal of all brew, gems, rails, rbenv, then reinstalled everything.  Still get the same error.  The brew install shows mysql2 available, but rails s says it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it finally!  Thank you:

```
https://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/07/getting-error-library-not-loaded.html
```

I had looked at a lot of these and tried the making a soft link to no effect, but this was the first time I found this one!:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

worked!